# Editable ALV with no limitation of lines

Tags: grid, edit, abap, alv

I need to create a report that displays an empty ALV with 4 columns and that is editable (the user can input on the fields of the ALV).

The ALV is going to be used as an input for the user and the data is then going to be read from the ALV.

What would be the best approach for this?

Comment: What size should be unlimited? Number of Columns, Visual size of fields, internal size of fields...?

Comment: Just the number of entries in the ALV

Comment: nothing can be unlimited, even universe is limited - did you encounter a limit or is that you just want an editable ALV (there are lots of examples in the web), and what exactly do you want to be the same as SM30 (because if you want ALV exactly like SM30 then it doesn't exist) - can you reformulate your question please?

Comment: Ok, yes, I edited the question. Sorry for the bad written question.

Comment: Basically, the core of my question is how can I create a report that displays an empty editable ALV with 4 columns, and which allows the inputed information on this ALV to be used for processing afterwards

Comment: `then going to be read from the ALV` read where? For what aim?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When youre setting the fieldcatalog, you need to declare "editable". For example

```
wa_fieldcat-fieldname = 'REMARKS'.
wa_fieldcat-scrtext_m = 'Purchase Order'.
wa_fieldcat-col_pos = 1.
wa_fieldcat-outputlen = 10.
wa_fieldcat-editable = 'X'.
wa_fieldcat-key = 'X'.
APPEND wa_fieldcat TO it_fieldcat.
CLEAR wa_fieldcat.
```

Then you need to declare in your process after input(PAI) the check changed data of the alv.

```
alv->checked_changed_data
```